# iText as text Extracting/Reading from PDF on android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I'm having a problem with iText. Other people say that iText is for PDF Creation only? and it can not read or extract text from a PDF. is that true?

If it is true then what are other options i can choose to EXTRACT text from PDF File and Save it on a Variable or Display it in Android device?

If iText is capable of Extracting text from PDF, then HOW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iText can extract text from PDFs. While it is true that it originated as a tool to create new and manipulate existing PDFs, it in the recent years also has become better and better at extracting text. This obviously implies that you should use a current iText version (5.3.x) for text extraction.

The book "iText in Action, second edition" by the main iText developer, Bruno Lowagie, explains basic iText text extraction in chapter 15, and the samples from that chapter are available in the iText Sourceforge SVN repository, cf. [Samples for chapter 15](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/book/src/part4/chapter15). A good starting point is [ExtractPageContentSorted2](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/book/src/part4/chapter15/ExtractPageContentSorted2.java) which extracts the text of a whole page.

If you have special requirements, you may use [ExtractPageContentSorted1](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/book/src/part4/chapter15/ExtractPageContentSorted1.java) as a starting point which explicitly defines a text extraction strategy; depending on your requirements you will need your own startegy. If you want the text from a specific region only, look at [ExtractPageContentArea](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/book/src/part4/chapter15/ExtractPageContentArea.java).

To really fine tune the text extraction capabilities of iText, you should have a look at the itext-question mailing list archive (e.g. [at nabble.com](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/)) as recently the iText text extraction API was extended to serve additional use cases.

Comment: @ChristianEricParan BTW, if you have trouble extracting text from a specific PDF, not from PDFs in general, please provide an appropriate sample PDF for inspection.

Comment: what do you mean by strategy? what if used a keyword and i want the whole sentence/paragraph where it is located. how would i implement it as a strategy in iText?

Comment: @ChristianEricParan The text rendering strategy is the object the parser reports the positioned text fragments from the PDF page content to. If you look at code of the samples above you will see in ExtractPageContentSorted1 that some LocationTextExtractionStrategy is instantiated. That strategy implementation collects all the text fragments from one page and, when asked for the text, sorts it top to bottom and left to right and returns the sorted text to you. For your requirement you could create a copy of that startegy class and constrain the result to the surrounding of your key word.

Comment: Thank you for your Time again. if you do not mind, will you give a 1 liner example of how to `constrain the result to the surrounding of your key word`. I was thinking of when the text is extracted from a PDF and saved in a `String` Variable I would search from that string rather from the PDF. is that a good approach?

Comment: If the content of that string variable looks good, i.e. if it represents the page content good enough, yes, that approach is ok. There may be situations, though, which require special handling, e.g. in case of multi column text where you want to extract data from one column only.

Comment: Thank you again. I got another problem, when I extract contans from a PDF and saved it in a variable the contents will have newline for everyline in a PDF instead of continues content. PDF Content Example: `ExtractPageContentSorted1 that some LocationTextExtractionStrategy is instantiated. That strategy` PDF Content saved in a Variable: `ExtractPageContentSorted1 that some\n LocationTextExtractionStrategy is instantiated. That strategy\n`

Comment: @Christian As soon as the text is layout-ed in a pdf, the information whether multiple lines form a paragraph is lost. All there remains are individual lines. Using advanced heuristics you may try and guess which lines belong together, but such heuristics are not in the strategies bundled with iText. Thus, you get a string containing all the text lines separated by \n.

Comment: ahh. so in this case I need a code that would fix the contents in the string?

Comment: Coding that, i.e. recognition of paragraphs,  in general is not trivial. Depending on your PDFs, it might be easier, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use below code to extract text from pdf :


String pat = data.getData().getPath();
File f = new File(pat);
//f is file path of pdf file
read = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(f));

parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(read);

strw = new StringWriter();

stretegy = parser.processContent(j, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());

strw.write(stretegy.getResultantText());

String da = strw.toString();

//set extracted text from pdf file 
//to Edit-text    
edt1.setText(da);
```