# How to open pdf file using iText in Android?

Tags: java, android, itext

I'm new in Android . I'm implementing PDF document using iText in Android . I want to read PDF document in my application. I don't have an idea how to access PDF doc in my app. I have created but when I run the application I get exception for `FileNotFoundException` and I also import a PDF file in SD card through DD-MS. But the PDF file does not open in Android. Here is my code:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64.InputStream;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    private static String FILE = "xyz.pdf";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        PdfReader reader = null;
        String str = null;
        int n = 0;
        try
        {
            istr =(InputStream) assetManager.open("xyz.pdf");

            reader=new PdfReader(istr);
            n=reader.getNumberOfPages();
            Log.e("n value:","-> " +n);
            str=reader.getPageContent(2).toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOne);
        tv.setText(str);

    }

}
```

Comment: please refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005902/itext-as-text-extracting-reading-from-pdf-on-android
 , you should make some stackoverflow before posting question

Answer (score 5):

As far as i know,iText is only for PDF creation, it doesn't contain viewer part.It is a parser, not a renderer. So you need to choose some another library to view pdf.But theare are some excellent code example in SO which you can view whether it meets your requirement..

- [How to render PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android)
- [Reading a pdf file using iText library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853525/reading-a-pdf-file-using-itext-library)

You can try other solution rather than iText..
 - [Render a PDF file using Java on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android)
 - http://andpdf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/andpdf/trunk/

And an excellent working code last of all..
 - [Example of code to implement a PDF reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152956/example-of-code-to-implement-a-pdf-reader)

Answer (score -1):

We can Extract data from iText. Here i am extracting text from PDFs file and showing on Edit-text :

```
String path = data.getData().getPath();
File f = new File(path);

static PdfReader read;
read = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(f));

 PdfReaderContentParser parser;
parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(read);

StringWriter strw;
strw = new StringWriter();

TextExtractionStrategy stretegy;
stretegy = parser.processContent(j, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());

strw.write(stretegy.getResultantText());

String da = strw.toString();
   
edt1.setText(da);
```